# Cakephp route all model to different name

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I'm not quite sure how to do this, I'm not familiar enough with cakephp routing.

Basicly, I have model like: Contact and Project. However, after redesign and redevelop and using the same stuff but different term..

I need to change something like:

```
myapplication.com/contacts/add  --> myapplication.com/customers/add
myapplication.com/contacts/edit --> myapplication.com/customers/edit
myapplication.com/projects/add  --> myapplication.com/tasks/add
myapplication.com/projects/edit --> myapplication.com/tasks/edit
```

or any other view.
How should I do this?

I know standard way:

```
Router::connect('/dashboard', array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'dashboard'));  
Router::redirect('/projects/dashboard', '/dashboard');
```

I believe I can do it one by one, but that's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
Router::connect('/customers/:action', array('controller' => 'contacts'));  
Router::connect('/tasks/:action', array('controller' => 'projects'));
```

It might be also a good idea to read [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) about routing. It is explained there in detail how to do it.

Comment: As a programmer you should know that "its broken" is the most bad description of an issue you can give? ;)

Comment: sorry, I tried to edit it, but it won't let me for 5 minutes.. I was gonna erase the whole stuff.. and change the question to:

it works good, but for view page like http://myapplication.com/contacts/view/28.. it still keep using contacts

Comment: Change your URLs for the AJAX requests then? Still, what is it doing wrong? Do you get a 404 back or what exactly is wrong?

Comment: oh no, it's not the ajax, that is the wrong question.. the question that I was going to ask is:
it is working for myapplication.com/customers/add, but it's not working with myapplication.com/contacts/view/12. when I try to change the contacts to customer, it gives me customer controller could not be found

Comment: oo I found the answer. I need to use *